# Async/await in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a `Timer`:

```
var QueryReportTimer = new Timer(QueryReportTimerCallback, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
```

The important part here is the method `QueryReportTimerCallback`.

I have a few doubts here:

- Is it ok to have an `async void` method? In general it is not, but how can I avoid this when the timer callback is delegate `public delegate void TimerCallback(object state);?`
- Is it ok to have await inside `Parallel.ForEach`?

Method `QueryReportTimerCallback`:

```
private async void QueryReportTimerCallback(object state)
{
    if (await semaphoreQueryReportSlim.WaitAsync(10))
    {
        try
        {
            if (machineConfigurations != null)
            {
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    Parallel.ForEach(machineConfigurations.Where(x => x.QueryReport), async (configuration) =>
                    {
                        if (configuration.IsConnectionValid)
                        {
                            var queryReport = new QueryReport(configuration, ReportConfigurations, fileContainer, applicationConfiguration, logger);
                            await QueryAReport(configuration, queryReport);
                        }
                    })
                );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.LogError(e, e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphoreQueryReportSlim.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it ok to have an async void method?

Referencing [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

As already stated in the OP `async void` should be avoided as much as possible.

The one exception to that rule being for event handlers, which can be the loophole to achieving the desired behavior while still having the ability to catch and handle any thrown exceptions.

Create an event

```
event EventHandler QueryReportCallbackEvent = delegate { };
```

to be raised by the timer callback

```
private void QueryReportTimerCallback(object state) {
    QueryReportCallbackEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

The event handler allows `async void`, so now you can safely do

```
private async void QueryReportCallbackEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (await semaphoreQueryReportSlim.WaitAsync(10))
        await queryReportsCore();
}
```

> Is it ok to have await inside Parallel.ForEach?

**NO!!!!**

The async lambda

```
async (configuration) => ...
```

will be converted to `async void` which takes us right back to what was said in the beginning. *`async void` BAD!!!*

Instead refactor that lambda out into its own method that returns a `Task`

```
private async Task HandleReport(MachineConfiguration configuration) {
    if (configuration.IsConnectionValid) {
        var queryReport = new QueryReport(configuration, ReportConfigurations, fileContainer, applicationConfiguration, logger);
        await QueryAReport(configuration, queryReport);
    }
}
```

and this will now allow for the use of `Task.WhenAll` with all the machine configurations retrieved from the query.

```
var tasks = machineConfigurations
                .Where(x => x.QueryReport)
                .Select(configuration => HandleReport(configuration));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This actually removes the need for the `Paralell.ForEach`.

Here is the complete code for what was described above.

```
//CTOR
public MyClass() {
    QueryReportCallbackEvent += QueryReportCallbackEventHandler;
    var QueryReportTimer = new Timer(QueryReportTimerCallback, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
}

event EventHandler QueryReportCallbackEvent = delegate { };

private void QueryReportTimerCallback(object state) {
    QueryReportCallbackEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private async void QueryReportCallbackEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (await semaphoreQueryReportSlim.WaitAsync(10))
        await queryReportsCore();
}

private async Task queryReportsCore() {
    try {
        if (machineConfigurations != null) {
            var tasks = machineConfigurations
                            .Where(x => x.QueryReport)
                            .Select(configuration => HandleReport(configuration));

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.LogError(e, e.Message);
    } finally {
        semaphoreQueryReportSlim.Release();
    }
}

private async Task HandleReport(MachineConfiguration configuration) {
    if (configuration.IsConnectionValid) {
        var queryReport = new QueryReport(configuration, ReportConfigurations, fileContainer, applicationConfiguration, logger);
        await QueryAReport(configuration, queryReport);
    }
}
```

Lastly take note of how the functions were broken down into smaller chunks that allowed for cleaner, more easy to read code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case I swallow an exceptions. Does this mean that I don't need to worry about "async void" in callback method? If we ignore fact that would be nicer, cleaner, more readable and by the book.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Where are you swallowing exception? if an exception is thrown in your async ForEach callback it wont get caught by that catch block you have there as it will be on a different thread. async voids are also called *fire and forget* as there is no telling what happens to them when invoked.

Comment: I am trying to understand what is benefit of using EventHandler? In both cases you will lose information about exception. Since event handler is also async void.

Comment: @Raskolnikov as I said before event handlers are the one exception (pardon the pun) to that rule. `async void` on event handlers are allowed. Read the reference link in the answer.

Comment: But... `Parallel.ForEach` runs something in parallel, while `WhenAll` guarantees that all tasks will be finished by this point of the execution, but DOES NOT guarantees parallelism, both things are way different, am I mistaken? Why would exchange one with another?

Comment: Do you happen to know how to _translate_ `Parallel.ForEach`'s `localInit` to `Task.WhenAll`?

Comment: @t3chb0t can you provide more details? The first things that jumps out at me is using a Select but I would need more context about what you are asking.

Comment: Some of the `Prallel.ForEach` overloads allow you to specify a _local_ variable via the `localInit` that you can pass to each iteration to the _body_ and thus share some state for at least a couple of loops, without instantiating it for each element. I was wondering if a similar behavior could be accomplished by using `Task.WhenAll`... but I guess it's a question on it's own :-)

Comment: That was amazing and saved my night. Thank you!

Comment: Task.WhenAll is not always, and in my case ever, a suitable replacement for Parallel.ForEach because I use the overload which limits how many concurrent processes can be run. I've tried swapping this out with the SemaphoreSlim pattern, but performance-wise, it has been so much faster for me to use Parallel.ForEach and just do a .Wait() if I have asynchronous processing to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

.net6 now supports Parallel.ForEachAsync

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. While this might be a good answer on some site, it is not a good answer on Code Review. A good answer on Code Review contains at least one insightful observation about the code. Alternate code only solutions are considered poor answers and may be down voted or deleted by the community. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/152097)